# Issue blocking & redirecting access to all directories on server using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Essentially I would like to block access and redirect users to a page called `test.com/redirect/page.php` from all directories unless a specific file is visited.

For example I would like to block users and redirect from the following:

`https://test.com/folder1/` should block with a 403 Forbidden error & redirect to `test.com/page.php` it should redirect because there is no `index.php` in that directory and no other file was specified in that url request.

`https://test.com/folder1/page1.php` is visited it should load no problem.

How can this done using the main htaccess file in directory.

Comment: Presumably you are already seeing a 403 response, just some other default "Apache" response?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to configure a custom 403 error document. For example:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /redirect/page.php
```

There is no external "redirect". The 403 error document is served by an internal subrequest (the visible URL does not change) whenever Apache triggers a 403 response.

You should also ensure that directory listings (mod_autoindex) are disabled, so that a 403 is indeed triggered when a `DirectoryIndex` document is not present in the requested directory.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument

Comment: I am struggling to understand how I can trigger the 403 error at the right times. The rules for when it needs to be triggered are depicted in the post

Comment: The 403 is automatically triggered by Apache (mod_autoindex) when you request a _directory_ that does not contain `index.php` (or any `DirectoryIndex` document) - this satisfies the criteria you've stated in the question... "it should redirect because there is no index.php in that directory and no other file was specified in that url request." You do not normally need to manually trigger the 403 yourself in this scenario. What are you currently seeing when making a request of the form `/folder1/` (when `/folder1/index.php` does not exist) as stated in your question?

Answer (score 0):

to redirect to homepage if the request is not for a file or dir, you can use the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ / [L]
```

Regards!